# How to add a new character combination to an existing keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, fonts, keyboard-layout

In my native language keyboard layout, a certain combination of letters produces the intended character. For example, for the single letter say 'हि', I need to type h then i, using the corresponding keyboard layout.

I came across an issue where in, a certain combination of letters, instead of producing the required character, is retaining the individually typed letters. How do I add my own combination for an existing keyboard layout?

Further details:-
Upon going through the existing fonts for that particular native language, I noticed that the required character doesn't exist at all, in any of the supported fonts for that language. Please let me know the steps in getting that particular letter combination to display the intended character. Thanks.

Comment: In your keyboard, how do you make the keys "hi" come out as "hi" or as हि ?

Comment: By switching the keyboards. I switch from Eng to Hindi. Anyways, I found the solution. Looks like I was using the wrong font on the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough if we change the keyboard, the editor being used must reflect the appropriate font. In my case, I had to change the editor's font from Serif to the appropriate native font. It then showed the required characters perfectly.

Comment: how did you make the keyboard mapping?

Comment: @BerryTsakala You can use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) tool. I have detailed the steps (for my specific case) [here](https://github.com/srix55/sanskrit-kagapa-windows)